# Split string and add unique strings to list in java

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have the following list of strings containing words.

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList();
words.add("hello, hi, henry");
words.add("hello1, hi1, henry1");
words.add("hello, hi, henry");
```

How can I loop through the words list, extract each element separated by a comma and generate a new list with unique elements. Output list should contain only the unique elements from the original list: hello, hi, henry, hello1, hi1, henry1. Wondering if there is an easier way to do this using streams in java 8 Thank you.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually compile right now...

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for catching that. I just edited the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach.

- Stream the list.
- split each string on the comma.
- flatMap each array to single stream of words.
- trim the white space from each word.
- use distinct to ignore duplicates.
- assign to a list.

```
List<String> result = words.stream()
                .flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split(",")))
                .map(String::trim).distinct().toList();

System.out.println(result);
```

Prints

```
[hello, hi, henry, hello1, hi1, henry1]
```

Comment: I was pretty close. Changing from map to flatMap did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `str.split(",\\s*")` to eliminate the white-space after comma in the first place, instead of doing `.map(String::trim)` afterwards.

Comment: I agree.  I was considering the possibility that the entire string could have started and ended with white space so I thought this was the easiest way to eliminate it. It would have been better to trim before splitting.